# Why the object is not spinning at all when moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, Transform toPosition, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            objectToMove.Rotate(throwSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition.position) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition.position, time);

            yield return null;
        }
        
        var naviParent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
        StartCoroutine(ThrowBack(objectToMove, naviParent.transform.position , duration));
    }
```

Then :

```
IEnumerator ThrowBack(Transform objectToMove,Vector3 originalPosition , float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

        float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, originalPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;
        objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, originalPosition, time);
        yield return null;
    }

    objectToMove.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I tried :

```
objectToMove.Rotate(throwSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

What I want to do is when the objectToMovei s start moving to also start spinning and when the objectToMove is getting close to the target about 5 distance from the target slowly decrease the spinning speed and stop complete the spinning when reaching the target.

Same logic when the object is moving back spin and then slowly decrease the spinning when getting distance 5 to stop spinning. but now the objectToMove is not spinning at all.

Answer (score 0):

its not spinnig because you are not telling it to spin.

A common way to approach this would be to use Quaternion.Lerp (or Slerp)
if your normalized position within the animation can be expressed as x

```
float x= counter/duration;
Quaternion startRotation=objectToMove.rotation;
Quaternion endRotation=?
objectToMove.rotation=Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation,endRotation,x);
```

I left your end rotation out as you'd need to somehow provide it (probably as next parameter in the IEnumerator call)

This will give you linear motion. If you want nicer motion, you can do

```
x = Mathf.SmoothStep(0,1,x);
```